# a small vue issue about set value to object.value

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

```html
<template>
    <button @click="random(randomNum)">Click to plus {{count}}</button>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue"
const count = ref ()
const randomNum = ref (Math.floor(Math.random()*1000))
function random(randomNum) {
  count.value=randomNum;
}
</script>
```

When I use `count.value = randomNum.value`, the result is not showing. I think `randomNum` is an object. If I set value to `count.value`, it should use `randomNum.value`, but it's not rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `randomNum` ref is only initialized to a random number **once**:

```html
<script setup>
                    /* set only once */
const randomNum = ref(Math.floor(Math.random()*1000))
⋮
</script>
```

That `randomNum` ref is passed to `random()` in the `click`-handler, but that ref's value never changes, so the clicks will appear to do nothing:

```html
<template>                  
  <button @click="random(randomNum)">Click</button>
</template>
```

### Solution

Instead of passing the `randomNum` ref, generate a new random number inside `random()` on every call:

```html
<script setup>
function random() {
                       /* new random number */
  count.value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
}
⋮
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="random()">Click</button>
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-gen-random-num?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<template>
   <button @click="random()">Click to plus {{count}}</button>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const count = ref(0)
    const randomNum = ref(Math.floor(Math.random()*1000))

    const random = () => {
      count.value = randomNum.value;
    }

    return {
      count,
      random,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: my question is why I use count.value = randomNum.value, it will not working normally. could you give me some explanations?

Comment: i think because u define same variable outside and inside function `const randomNum = ref()` and `function random(randomNum){}`